# Meaning of useServerConfiguration() and createIndex() in spring data for elastic search

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hi I recently upgraded from spring-data-elasticsearch 1.3.2 to 2.0.1. I noticed that there are two new attributes of @Document annotation:

```
boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;
boolean createIndex() default true;
```

I'm struggling to find a documentation saying what these attributes actually mean?

BTW: Also I'm quite surprised why spring data elastic search does not document properly any of the attrbutes of @Document.

Answer (score 1):

`createIndex=true` indicates that when Spring application starts, if configured index does not exist, then Spring creates the index.

`useServerConfiguration=true` indicates that when the index is created by Spring, Spring does not set the following settings in the created index: shards, replicas, refreshInterval and indexStoreType. These settings will be Elasticsearch defaults (server configuration).